# Create/Extract field variable without moving to the top of the class Intellij

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Intellij IDEs provide a great possibilities to speed up development. There is one useful feature like extracting/creating field variable.
It works great, but one thing that I found annoying that it is moving up to the top of the class, and than it is hard to find the place where I just have been working.

Is there any way to disable this feature (moving to the top/variable declaration block) ?

Maybe there are other ways I can achieve this ?

Comment: doesn't it return when you click ENTER 2 or 3 times, in eclipse it works so...

Comment: RE: navigating -- `Navigate | Back` or `Navigate | Last Edit Location` ?